# How to fix Race-condition, created duplicate class Error

Tags: java, multithreading, mongodb, tomcat, morphia

When I start my tomcat server I get this error: 
2015 10:25:50 PM org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.MappedClass getOrCreateInstance
SEVERE: Race-condition, created duplicate class: class com.calendar.model.watchers.AccountWatcher

From what I can tell it is coming from Morphia, but I'm unsure why it's happening or how to fix it.

The code in Morphia that the error appears to be coming from is this:

```
private Object getOrCreateInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
    if (mapr.instanceCache.containsKey(clazz))
        return mapr.instanceCache.get(clazz);

    Object o = mapr.getOptions().objectFactory.createInstance(clazz);
    Object nullO = mapr.instanceCache.put(clazz, o);
    if (nullO != null)
        if(log.isErrorEnabled())
            log.error("Race-condition, created duplicate class: " + clazz);

    return o;

}
```

The code for AccountWatcher is:

```
package com.calendar.model.watchers;

import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;  
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.PreLoad;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.PrePersist;
import com.calendar.exception.DataAccessException;
import com.calendar.model.Account;
import com.calendar.model.Partner;
import com.calendar.util.MongoUtils;

public class AccountWatcher {
  final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountWatcher.class);

  @PrePersist
  void prePersist(Account account) {
    if (account.getId() == null) {// This is for create
      account.setId(MongoUtils.getGuid());
      account.setDateCreated(new Date());
      Partner owner = account.getOwner();
      if (owner == null || StringUtils.isEmpty(owner.getId())) {
        throw new DataAccessException("Owner :" + owner
            + " doesn't exist for account :" + account);
      }
    } else { // This is for update

    }
    account.setDateModified(new Date());
  }

  @PreLoad
  void preLoad(Account account) {
    if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
      log.debug("Account watcher @PreLoad executing ...");
    }
  }
}
```

And the code for the Account class is:

```
package com.calendar.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat.Shape;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize.Typing;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.EntityListeners;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Indexed;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Reference;
import com.calendar.model.serializers.PartnerDeSerializer;
import com.calendar.model.serializers.PartnerListSerializer;
import com.calendar.model.serializers.PartnerSerializer;
import com.calendar.model.watchers.AccountWatcher;

@ToString
@EntityListeners(AccountWatcher.class)
@Entity("accounts")
@Data
public class Account {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String timezone;

  @JsonSerialize(using = PartnerSerializer.class, typing = Typing.STATIC)
  @JsonDeserialize(using = PartnerDeSerializer.class)
  @Reference
  private Partner owner;

  @JsonSerialize(using = PartnerListSerializer.class, typing = Typing.STATIC)
  @Reference
  private List<Partner> associatedPartners;

  @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
  private Date dateCreated;
  @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
  private Date dateModified;
  @Indexed(unique = true, dropDups = true)
  private String externalId;
  private Integer externalVersionNumber;
  private List<EList> elists;

  public Account() {
    associatedPartners = new ArrayList<Partner>();
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help that can be provided.

Comment: The actual stacktrace would help.

Comment: you could use http://vmlens.com. It should detect all data races.

Comment: @evanchooly There is no stackrace with this error.  The error comes from morphia and all it does is log that error and the class that it has the problem with.  I will update my original question to include the code from Morphia that logs the error.  And thanks Thomas I'll take a look into that.

Answer (score 0):

ah, i see.  I'm not sure why the decision was made to log that as an error (and conversely, why that logic isn't synchronized)  but it's just a logging message.  It's not a real problem unless, of course, your listener is mutable and having two instances is an actual problem.

Comment: The listener is predefined by Morphia and I haven't changed anything. From what I can tell the class itself isn't being changed in any way so it doesn't seem mutable though it creates the logger for each instance.  It seems odd that it would be fine and yet log the error unless the listener is by default mutable, but it's also entirely possible that it's not actually a problem and Morphia is just crossing its T's and dotting its I's. Is your recommendation that this can be ignored then? Or is more research/information required?

Comment: You can probably ignore this error since AccountWatcher is stateless.